# How do i suppress the editor in dpkg-source --commit calls?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, packaging, dpkg

On Ubuntu precise

I am calling "dpkg -q --commit ./ patchsetname"

When I do this it decides to open an editor using the select editor binary.

I want to suppress that.  Any thoughts?

I'd rather not have to interrupt the exec syscall with a shared library and filter for the editor query.  There should be a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way to do this.  The best work around is to create new patches and add them to the package patches definitions and series.  This can suck in some cases.  I've taken to placing unique identifier strings throughout my debian package definitions so I can sed replace values before building packages.  However this really limits some of the things you can do during a package build.  For better or for worse.  I think worse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just fixed this with the following:

```
EDITOR=/bin/true dpkg-source -q --commit . patchsetname
```

This will (obviously) use `true` instead of `nano` and at least on kubuntu this seems to work fine.

Comment: Works a treat on Debian 9 (Stretch) as well.